# Sonarqube analysis not working

Tags: php, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I have set up SonarQube server on my local system and run sonar runner. it will run good with .html file but when i am trying to run with php file, it failed and showing error like:

> java illegal language exception blame sample.php file.

I installed all plugin as below.

- git
- java
- javascript
- web
- php
- c#

but it is not working.

Comment: Can you post the log you are getting ? what are the versions of SonarQube and the different plugins ? can you share your sonar-project.properties file ? What have you tried ? There is not enough information in your question for anyone to help you out, please pinpoint the problem and give information if you want anyone to help you.

Comment: set sonar-project properties file with language = php. my code analysis is working without .php file . sonarqube verison is 5.6, sonar-scanner verison is 2.8. getting below error when trying to analyse .php file "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to blame file index.php
        at org.sonarsource.scm.git.JGitBlameCommand.blame(JGitBl" i have

Answer (score 4):

You get this blame error because you are trying to analyze a set of files on which you have uncommitted changes.

To fix this:

- Either you make sure that you a running an analysis on source code that has been freshly checked out from your version control system (and not changed since then-
- Or you tell SonarQube to not try to get SCM information

  - You will find this in the "Administration > Configuration > SCM" settings page: it is called "Disable the SCM Sensor"

Comment: Can you please validate the answer?

Comment: I just followed the step mentioned by you and it has been started to work well.

Comment: Fabrice is asking you to validate his answer : see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

One more possibility to end up with this error "java illegal language exception blame file-name file" is that your repository could have been shallow cloned with depth=1.

[image]

In my case, we configured our jenkins to do a shallow clone with depth = 1 and this error came up. When I changed the depth = 2 and re ran the jenkins job, sonar:sonar worked fine and results are pushed to the sonar server.

Look at the field "Shallow clone depth" in the attached image.
Hope this helps.